# Google Cloud Shell HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: This can occur if a VM was created with no service account or scopes

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run a simple script from 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/data_analysis/lab2/python/grepc.py
(this code is a Dataflow pipeline connecting to Google Storage)

It worked last week. But when I am running it now, I always get the same error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grepc.py", line 50, in <module>
    run()
  File "grepc.py", line 44, in run
    | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 391, in __init__
    skip_header_lines=skip_header_lines)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 89, in __init__
    validate=validate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 105, in __init__
    self._validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/options/value_provider.py", line 109, in _f
    return fnc(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 165, in _validate
    match_result = FileSystems.match([pattern], limits=[1])[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystems.py", line 131, in match
    return filesystem.match(patterns, limits)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsfilesystem.py", line 138, in match
    raise BeamIOError("Match operation failed", exceptions)
apache_beam.io.filesystem.BeamIOError: Match operation failed with exceptions {'gs://{MY_BUCKET}/javahelp/*.java': HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(u' This can occur if a VM was created with no service account or scopes.',)}
```

I have no idea how to solve this. And a lot of Googling did not help neither.

Comment: Is this error happening on a GCP Compute Engine instance or where?

Comment: I am running it in the default cloud shell.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Acquiring new user credentials to use for Application Default Credentials fixed my problem.

This is what I used

> gcloud auth application-default login

It is well documented here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login

and you can find the explanation here : *This command is useful when you are developing code that would normally use a service account but need to run the code in a local development environment where it's easier to provide user credentials. The credentials will apply to all API calls that make use of the Application Default Credentials client library*

Another solution I found was : download keyfile for the compute engine service account and export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point towards the keyfile

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the {MYBUCKET} in the error message is not literal and was replaced by your bucket name.

If you're running this from a GCE VM instance, can you run this command and paste the output here?

gcloud compute instances describe {instance-name} --zone {instance-zone}

The above would tell you what service accounts and scopes your VM instance has. And also:

gcloud projects get-iam-policy {project-name}

This would tell you what service accounts your project has. Please wipe out the project number or any info that you deem sensitive.

Comment: Hi David, yes MYBUKCET is replaced by my bucket which exists. I am running the command just in the google cloud shell. Meaning I sudo install the install packages and that's it. So I am not using an extra VM and I am also not aware of a service account I am giving permissions. It's a big project and there are several service accounts. Is there a way to find out which one I should check?

Comment: I have to add that running this script https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/data_analysis/lab2/python/grep.py works. But connection to google stoarge raises the error from above. Still don't know what to do. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you paste the output of the commands I specified (with any sensitive info wiped out)? I just want to make sure you have the right scopes and service accounts.